# How do I dump the Stack Overflow database?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-dump

I want to use the Stack Overflow database for a data classification project. How do I dump the Stack Overflow database?

Answer (score 23):

You can download the data dump (produced monthly) at: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

You will need a 7zip decompressor, XML parsing code, and probably a database to load the data into.

You may also be interested in https://data.stackexchange.com/ which has already done all this for you.

Comment: There is an RSS feed here: feed://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss

Comment: Stackql.net is no longer available. Do you know another site that provides this functionality?

Comment: @Marcel: SE now runs a regularly-updated interactive query thingamajig here: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shog9 thanks! the `thingamajig` *is* awesome! Is the (http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) also up-to-date? maybe we should link to that as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL I have a schema and a script written in ruby that will load the data. Just grab the latest [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), create a database, load [this schema](http://code.google.com/p/geeqe/source/browse/trunk/scripts/schema.sql), modify [this loader script](http://code.google.com/p/geeqe/source/browse/trunk/scripts/load.rb) to point to your database and then run the script. It only takes a few minutes to load all the data.

Comment: Your script and schema worked like a charm.

Comment: Cannot access the database files anymore. Anyone know what's wrong? There are backups? Wanna map full site to search offline :)

Answer (score 0):

I just made a [slow Python script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/python-script-to-import-create-sqlite3-database-from-so-data-dump) to import the dump to a SQLite3 database.

It's designed to run on my RAMless netbook, so it doesn't make a single `COMMIT` for all `INSERT`s, but rather `COMMIT`s every `INSERT`. I'll make a fast RAM sucker version tomorrow.