# Python script to import/create SQLite3 database from SO data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump, scripts

Here is a small script that I needed, and feel that I should share the community. I'm sorry if you find something extremely unpythonic or a bad practice, but it's a quick and dirty script and I should have gone to sleep a few hours ago.

It creates a new SQLite db if needed, creates all the tables, and dumps the dump in them.

Without more presentation, my WTF of the date:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import logging

ANATHOMY = {
    'badges': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
        'name':'TEXT',
        'date':'DATETIME',
    },
    'comments': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'PostId':'INTEGER',
        'Score':'INTEGER',
        'Text':'TEXT',
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
    },
    'posts': {
        'Id':'INTEGER', 
        'PostTypeId':'INTEGER', # 1: Question, 2: Answer
        'ParentID':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
        'AcceptedAnswerId':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'Score':'INTEGER',
        'ViewCount':'INTEGER',
        'Body':'TEXT',
        'OwnerUserId':'INTEGER', # (present only if user has not been deleted) 
        'LastEditorUserId':'INTEGER',
        'LastEditorDisplayName':'TEXT', #="Rich B" 
        'LastEditDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823" 
        'LastActivityDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480" 
        'CommunityOwnedDate':'DATETIME', #(present only if post is community wikied)
        'Title':'TEXT',
        'Tags':'TEXT',
        'AnswerCount':'INTEGER',
        'CommentCount':'INTEGER',
        'FavoriteCount':'INTEGER',
        'ClosedDate':'DATETIME',
    },
    'votes': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'PostId':'INTEGER',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
        'VoteTypeId':'INTEGER',
           # -   1: AcceptedByOriginator
           # -   2: UpMod
           # -   3: DownMod
           # -   4: Offensive
           # -   5: Favorite
           # -   6: Close
           # -   7: Reopen
           # -   8: BountyStart
           # -   9: BountyClose
           # -  10: Deletion
           # -  11: Undeletion
           # -  12: Spam
           # -  13: InformModerator
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
    },
    'users': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'Reputation':'INTEGER',
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'DisplayName':'DATETIME',
        'LastAccessDate':'DATETIME',
        'WebsiteUrl':'TEXT',
        'Location':'TEXT',
        'Age':'INTEGER',
        'AboutMe':'TEXT',
        'Views':'INTEGER',
        'UpVotes':'INTEGER',
        'DownVotes':'INTEGER',
  },
}

def dump_files(file_names, anathomy, 
                dump_path='c:\\temp\\', 
                dump_database_name = 'so-dump.db',
                create_query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [{table}]({fields})',
                insert_query='INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})',
                log_filename='so-parser.log'):

    logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(dump_path, log_filename),level=logging.INFO)
    db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(dump_path, dump_database_name))

    for file in file_names:
        print "Opening {0}.xml".format(file)
        with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml')) as xml_file:
            tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
            table_name = file

            sql_create = create_query.format(
                                table=table_name, 
                                fields=", ".join(['{0} {1}'.format(name, type) for name, type in anathomy[table_name].items()]))
            print('Creating table {0}'.format(table_name))

            try:
                logging.info(sql_create)
                db.execute(sql_create)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.warning(e)

            for events, row in tree:
                try:
                    logging.debug(row.attrib.keys())

                    db.execute(insert_query.format(
                                table=table_name, 
                                columns=', '.join(row.attrib.keys()), 
                                values=('?, ' * len(row.attrib.keys()))[:-2]),
                                row.attrib.values())
                    print ".",
                except Exception, e:
                    logging.warning(e)
                    print "x",
                finally:
                    row.clear()
            print "\n"
            db.commit()
            del(tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dump_files(ANATHOMY.keys(), ANATHOMY)
```

Feel free to make any suggestions. I'll try to improve on it, but as it is now, it *Works on my machine*<sup>TM</sup>.

[image: I'll go to bed now, with my lovely snake.]

---

### Correctly working, never using more than 200 MB for the dump.

`timeit` pending, but fast enough.

Thanks to Kyle Cronin for making me wonder if I was on the right path. My previous algorithm had important problems.

This script uses `lxml`, that allows you to have only one node in memory at a time, avoiding the need of <del>using regexes for parsing `XML`</del>committing a sin.

Comment: What sort of performance do you get? How long does it take to run?

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: it's still running. For the `users` table, about an hour. It's **NOT** optimized for speed. As you can see, I loop over with the insert. An `insertmany` should speed things up a little. Not printing the inserts speeds up a little. I'd say that you'd have to keep it running overnight (what I'll do) in a slow spec machine (my EEE 1000HA netbook). I wanted to keep the least necessary data in memory. Tomorrow will `timeit`.

Comment: @voyager's mask: Yikes! I'm not familiar with the code you're using to insert into the DB, but it doesn't look like you're wrapping your writes into 1 transaction. If you don't, SQLite writes to the file with every since insert. If you stick a "begin" at the beginning" and an "end" at the end, you'll probably discover at least a 10x speedup, possibly more.

Comment: @Kyle Cronnin: I'm aware of that, but I wanted first to make sure that the script didn't blow up because of some non-foreseen situation with the xml files. Right now, the script is going the lazy, ugly way: commit and write to disk on every insert.

Comment: Remember that I'm running this on a netbook, RAM comes at a premium. On the desktop will try dumping all the xml to memory and inserting in bulk.

Comment: @voyager: OK, OK, it was just a tip. I wrote a similar script in Python several months ago to produce my SQLite versions of the early data dumps (April and May, I think). IIRC it took about half an hour to load the data from a dump into a SQLite file, and that was with the 1-transaction trick.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: thanks for the tip anyway. Do you remember what parser you used then? Also, keep in mind that the dump has doubled in the last months ;) Will change the script now anyway, as I'm seeing that I'm inserting at the wooping speed of 1 Kb per second...

Comment: Damn! That was a **big** change! But I think that I have problems with oone  of the files. Could it be that the badges file is malformed at he end?

Comment: That's a pretty disturbing photo. I've seen videos of pythons *swallowing* prey larger than that kid!

Comment: @pavium: check the history of the non-answer bellow, or just google image python...

Comment: @voyager: Actually, I used regular expressions. I read the file in small chunks (I think 16MB?) and did regular expression matching on that. It wasn't pretty, but it worked well enough.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: don't let Welbog hear you! `lxml` turned out to be much more flexible than I knew. I could take the dump in a few dozen minutes and less than 200 MB.