# Scripts to Convert the Monthly Data Dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump, convert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

As [suggested in another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/is-there-a-sqlite-data-dump-for-the-latest-release/28212#28212), if you have scripts or small programs in any language that convert the monthly data dump into another format, please share them here.

Comment: Damnit, I just posted an mostly identical question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats - to prevent us both deleting our questions at the same time, which one shall we keep? You could delete this, or I could move my excessive guidelines here and delete my question..

Answer (score 0):

### [Python script to import/create SQLite3 database from SO data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/python-script-to-import-create-sqlite3-database-from-so-data-dump)

Requires:

- Python 2.5+
- `lxml`

```
import sqlite3
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import logging

ANATHOMY = {
    'badges': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
        'name':'TEXT',
        'date':'DATETIME',
    },
    'comments': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'PostId':'INTEGER',
        'Score':'INTEGER',
        'Text':'TEXT',
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
    },
    'posts': {
        'Id':'INTEGER', 
        'PostTypeId':'INTEGER', # 1: Question, 2: Answer
        'ParentID':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
        'AcceptedAnswerId':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'Score':'INTEGER',
        'ViewCount':'INTEGER',
        'Body':'TEXT',
        'OwnerUserId':'INTEGER', # (present only if user has not been deleted) 
        'LastEditorUserId':'INTEGER',
        'LastEditorDisplayName':'TEXT', #="Rich B" 
        'LastEditDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823" 
        'LastActivityDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480" 
        'CommunityOwnedDate':'DATETIME', #(present only if post is community wikied)
        'Title':'TEXT',
        'Tags':'TEXT',
        'AnswerCount':'INTEGER',
        'CommentCount':'INTEGER',
        'FavoriteCount':'INTEGER',
        'ClosedDate':'DATETIME',
    },
    'votes': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'PostId':'INTEGER',
        'UserId':'INTEGER',
        'VoteTypeId':'INTEGER',
           # -   1: AcceptedByOriginator
           # -   2: UpMod
           # -   3: DownMod
           # -   4: Offensive
           # -   5: Favorite
           # -   6: Close
           # -   7: Reopen
           # -   8: BountyStart
           # -   9: BountyClose
           # -  10: Deletion
           # -  11: Undeletion
           # -  12: Spam
           # -  13: InformModerator
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
    },
    'users': {
        'Id':'INTEGER',
        'Reputation':'INTEGER',
        'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
        'DisplayName':'DATETIME',
        'LastAccessDate':'DATETIME',
        'WebsiteUrl':'TEXT',
        'Location':'TEXT',
        'Age':'INTEGER',
        'AboutMe':'TEXT',
        'Views':'INTEGER',
        'UpVotes':'INTEGER',
        'DownVotes':'INTEGER',
  },
}

def dump_files(file_names, anathomy, 
                dump_path='c:\\temp\\', 
                dump_database_name = 'so-dump.db',
                create_query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [{table}]({fields})',
                insert_query='INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})',
                log_filename='so-parser.log'):

    logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(dump_path, log_filename),level=logging.INFO)
    db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(dump_path, dump_database_name))

    for file in file_names:
        print "Opening {0}.xml".format(file)
        with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml')) as xml_file:
            tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
            table_name = file

            sql_create = create_query.format(
                                table=table_name, 
                                fields=", ".join(['{0} {1}'.format(name, type) for name, type in anathomy[table_name].items()]))
            print('Creating table {0}'.format(table_name))

            try:
                logging.info(sql_create)
                db.execute(sql_create)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.warning(e)

            for events, row in tree:
                try:
                    logging.debug(row.attrib.keys())

                    db.execute(insert_query.format(
                                table=table_name, 
                                columns=', '.join(row.attrib.keys()), 
                                values=('?, ' * len(row.attrib.keys()))[:-2]),
                                row.attrib.values())
                    print ".",
                except Exception, e:
                    logging.warning(e)
                    print "x",
                finally:
                    row.clear()
            print "\n"
            db.commit()
            del(tree)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dump_files(ANATHOMY.keys(), ANATHOMY)
```