# Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/is-there-a-sqlite-data-dump-for-the-latest-release), perhaps we could collect together a bunch of scripts to convert the XML data-dump files into other formats, such as SQLite, MySQL and the likes.

To keep things consistent, some guidelines:

**If something changes in the data-dump**, and the old script no longer works, **make a new post** for the updated script.

**Don't depend on the machine having lots of memory**, reading the entire set of XML files into memory is probably going to cause a lot of machines to run out of memory - [some of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+stream+parser) should help with this..

**Mention version numbers of things you are using**, well, relevant things, like the programming language and any libraries. Linking to non-standard modules and such would be nice too

**Use the following template for all posted scripts:**

```
# {New format name}

{Implementation language}

Tested and working on release(s):

- {List of releases the script is known to work on}

----

    {code}
```

For example:

> ## SQLite3
>
> Python 2.6.4
>
> Tested and working on release(s):
>
> - Oct 2009
> - Nov 2009
>
> ---
>
> ```
> import sqlite3
> import magic
> magic.convert("*.xml")
> ```

Comment: It would be pretty nice to have a way to render the dumps the same way the SE sites are normally rendered in the browser.

Comment: Was the point of the question to have those scripts here or in a repository some place?

Comment: I can't get any of the python scripts to work and the C++ fails with "unknown column in PostHistory: ContentLicense".

Anyone willing to create a version in PHP or Perl? Or possibly fix the C++ version?

Answer (score 12):

### [Python script to import/create SQLite3 database from SO data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/python-script-to-import-create-sqlite3-database-from-so-data-dump)

Requires:

- Python 2.5+
- `lxml`

```
import sqlite3
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import logging

ANATHOMY = {
 'badges': {
  'Id':'INTEGER',
  'UserId':'INTEGER',
  'Name':'TEXT',
  'Date':'DATETIME',
 },
 'comments': {
  'Id':'INTEGER',
  'PostId':'INTEGER',
  'Score':'INTEGER',
  'Text':'TEXT',
  'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
  'UserId':'INTEGER',
 },
 'posts': {
  'Id':'INTEGER', 
  'PostTypeId':'INTEGER', # 1: Question, 2: Answer
  'ParentID':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
  'AcceptedAnswerId':'INTEGER', # (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
  'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
  'Score':'INTEGER',
  'ViewCount':'INTEGER',
  'Body':'TEXT',
  'OwnerUserId':'INTEGER', # (present only if user has not been deleted) 
  'LastEditorUserId':'INTEGER',
  'LastEditorDisplayName':'TEXT', #="Rich B" 
  'LastEditDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823" 
  'LastActivityDate':'DATETIME', #="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480" 
  'CommunityOwnedDate':'DATETIME', #(present only if post is community wikied)
  'Title':'TEXT',
  'Tags':'TEXT',
  'AnswerCount':'INTEGER',
  'CommentCount':'INTEGER',
  'FavoriteCount':'INTEGER',
  'ClosedDate':'DATETIME',
 },
 'votes': {
  'Id':'INTEGER',
  'PostId':'INTEGER',
  'UserId':'INTEGER',
  'VoteTypeId':'INTEGER',
           # -   1: AcceptedByOriginator
           # -   2: UpMod
           # -   3: DownMod
           # -   4: Offensive
           # -   5: Favorite
           # -   6: Close
           # -   7: Reopen
           # -   8: BountyStart
           # -   9: BountyClose
           # -  10: Deletion
           # -  11: Undeletion
           # -  12: Spam
           # -  13: InformModerator
  'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
  'BountyAmount':'INTEGER'
 },
 'users': {
  'Id':'INTEGER',
  'Reputation':'INTEGER',
  'CreationDate':'DATETIME',
  'DisplayName':'TEXT',
  'LastAccessDate':'DATETIME',
  'WebsiteUrl':'TEXT',
  'Location':'TEXT',
  'Age':'INTEGER',
  'AboutMe':'TEXT',
  'Views':'INTEGER',
  'UpVotes':'INTEGER',
  'DownVotes':'INTEGER',
  'EmailHash':'TEXT'
  },
}

def dump_files(file_names, anathomy, 
    dump_path='c:\\temp\\', 
    dump_database_name = 'so-dump.db',
    create_query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [{table}]({fields})',
    insert_query='INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})',
    log_filename='so-parser.log'):

 logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(dump_path, log_filename),level=logging.INFO)
 db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(dump_path, dump_database_name))

 for file in file_names:
  print "Opening {0}.xml".format(file)
  with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml')) as xml_file:
   tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
   table_name = file

   sql_create = create_query.format(
        table=table_name, 
        fields=", ".join(['{0} {1}'.format(name, type) for name, type in anathomy[table_name].items()]))
   print('Creating table {0}'.format(table_name))

   try:
    logging.info(sql_create)
    db.execute(sql_create)
   except Exception, e:
    logging.warning(e)

   for events, row in tree:
    try:
     logging.debug(row.attrib.keys())

     db.execute(insert_query.format(
        table=table_name, 
        columns=', '.join(row.attrib.keys()), 
        values=('?, ' * len(row.attrib.keys()))[:-2]),
        row.attrib.values())
     print ".",
    except Exception, e:
     logging.warning(e)
     print "x",
    finally:
     row.clear()
   print "\n"
   db.commit()
   del(tree)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
 dump_files(ANATHOMY.keys(), ANATHOMY)
```

Comment: Could someone with edit permission please update the ANATHOMY declaration in the script above with the following:
- Under 'votes', add 'BountyAmount':'INTEGER',
- Under 'users', change 'DisplayName':'DATETIME' to 'DisplayName':'TEXT'
- Under 'users', add 'EmailHash':'TEXT'
- Under 'badges', change 'name' to 'Name' and 'date' to 'Date'
Not sure if the badges change affects anything, but the others definitely affect what ends up in the database.

Comment: Nearly one year later, I did so. :) On Linux, change `dump_path='c:\\temp\\'` to something else - I would suggest "." for all systems. Executing it, I get an error about missing 'vote.xml' - guess I have to find it somewhere. :)

Comment: I slightly improved this code. It's [on github](https://github.com/testlnord/sedumpy). 
Now it works well with 2014.05 stackoverflow dump.

Answer (score 6):

### C++ (SQLite3, PostgreSQL)

- Source: https://github.com/sth/sodata/
- Requirements: libexpat, libsqlite3 or libpqxx
- Binary (Linux x64, Ubuntu): http://tejp.de/files/so/dbimport/soimport-r11_x64.tar.gz
- Binary (Linux i386, Debian): http://tejp.de/files/so/dbimport/soimport-r11_i386.tar.gz

Columns containing numeric values are converted to numbers, columns containing dates are converted to Unix timestamps and stored as numbers. Optionally indexes are added for all numeric columns. The import takes about 5-10 minutes for the pure data and about 10 minutes more if generating indexes.

#### Usage

To generate a SQLite database, start the `sqliteimport` program in a directory containing the data dumps XML files and it creates a `dump.db` in the same directory. If you don't want indexes (creating them takes some time), start the program with `sqliteimport -I`.

PostgreSQL support is still a little bit experimental. To generate a PostgreSQL database, start the `pgcopyimport` program in a directory containing the data dumps XML files. Pass a `-c` flag with the necessary database information, like `pgcopyimport -c "dbname=sodump user=so password=abc"`. The database needs to exist. *Warning:* This program creates big temporary files in `/var/tmp`, about as big as the single XML files. This is done to quickly load the data into the database with `COPY FROM`. The the temporary files are named `badges.pgdata`,...

If you don't want to create temporary files use the `pgimport` program instead, but this will be a lot slower. PostgreSQL import also skips the generation of indexes if the `-I` flag is added.

#### Other uses

The design should also be fairly flexible if you want to extract special data from the XML files, parse different XML files, or create something else than a SQLite/PostgreSQL database from the input.

Comment: The "source" link now returns a 404

Comment: @SedateAlien I fixed the link

Comment: Currently reporting: "unknown column in PostHistory: ContentLicense"

Answer (score 5):

If you are importing into MySQL, you might want to use the following MySQL script:

https://gist.github.com/gousiosg/7600626

No extra dependencies required

Comment: I just used this, it was a little clunky but totally handled its business

Answer (score 4):

I have a short C# program to help import the Posts table into SQL Server.  You can see an old version here:
[Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats).

If I remember and have time at home later I'll post updated code. The other tables were imported via Brent Ozar's instructions (with some modifications for schema changes):
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/how-to-import-the-stackoverflow-xml-into-sql-server/.

Answer (score 4):

[So-Slow](http://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow), is by far the fastest way to get data into SQL Server. It is still able to process current dumps in under 10 minutes, including tag splitting.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3

This is the same exact script as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28231/201314), except updated for Python 3 and the September 2016 data dump.

```
import sqlite3
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import logging

ANATHOMY = {
  'badges': {
    'Id': 'INTEGER',
    'UserId': 'INTEGER',
    'Class': 'INTEGER',
    'Name': 'TEXT',
    'Date': 'DATETIME',
    'TagBased': 'BOOLEAN',
  },
  'comments': {
    'Id': 'INTEGER',
    'PostId': 'INTEGER',
    'Score': 'INTEGER',
    'Text': 'TEXT',
    'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
    'UserId': 'INTEGER',
    'UserDisplayName': 'TEXT'
  },
  'posts': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'PostTypeId': 'INTEGER',  # 1: Question, 2: Answer
      'ParentId': 'INTEGER',  # (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
      'AcceptedAnswerId': 'INTEGER',  # (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
      'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
      'Score': 'INTEGER',
      'ViewCount': 'INTEGER',
      'Body': 'TEXT',
      'OwnerUserId': 'INTEGER',  # (present only if user has not been deleted)
      'OwnerDisplayName': 'TEXT',
      'LastEditorUserId': 'INTEGER',
      'LastEditorDisplayName': 'TEXT',  # ="Rich B"
      'LastEditDate': 'DATETIME',  #="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823"
      'LastActivityDate': 'DATETIME',  #="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480"
      'CommunityOwnedDate': 'DATETIME',  #(present only if post is community wikied)
      'Title': 'TEXT',
      'Tags': 'TEXT',
      'AnswerCount': 'INTEGER',
      'CommentCount': 'INTEGER',
      'FavoriteCount': 'INTEGER',
      'ClosedDate': 'DATETIME',
      'ContentLicense': 'TEXT'
  },
  'votes': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'PostId': 'INTEGER',
      'UserId': 'INTEGER',
      'VoteTypeId': 'INTEGER',
      # -   1: AcceptedByOriginator
      # -   2: UpMod
      # -   3: DownMod
      # -   4: Offensive
      # -   5: Favorite
      # -   6: Close
      # -   7: Reopen
      # -   8: BountyStart
      # -   9: BountyClose
      # -  10: Deletion
      # -  11: Undeletion
      # -  12: Spam
      # -  13: InformModerator
      'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
      'BountyAmount': 'INTEGER'
  },
  'posthistory': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'PostHistoryTypeId': 'INTEGER',
      'PostId': 'INTEGER',
      'RevisionGUID': 'TEXT',
      'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
      'UserId': 'INTEGER',
      'UserDisplayName': 'TEXT',
      'Comment': 'TEXT',
      'Text': 'TEXT'
  },
  'postlinks': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
      'PostId': 'INTEGER',
      'RelatedPostId': 'INTEGER',
      'PostLinkTypeId': 'INTEGER',
      'LinkTypeId': 'INTEGER'
  },
  'users': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'Reputation': 'INTEGER',
      'CreationDate': 'DATETIME',
      'DisplayName': 'TEXT',
      'LastAccessDate': 'DATETIME',
      'WebsiteUrl': 'TEXT',
      'Location': 'TEXT',
      'Age': 'INTEGER',
      'AboutMe': 'TEXT',
      'Views': 'INTEGER',
      'UpVotes': 'INTEGER',
      'DownVotes': 'INTEGER',
      'AccountId': 'INTEGER',
      'ProfileImageUrl': 'TEXT'
  },
  'tags': {
      'Id': 'INTEGER',
      'TagName': 'TEXT',
      'Count': 'INTEGER',
      'ExcerptPostId': 'INTEGER',
      'WikiPostId': 'INTEGER'
  }
}


def dump_files(file_names, anathomy,
             dump_path='.',
             dump_database_name='so-dump.db',
             create_query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table} ({fields})',
             insert_query='INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})',
             log_filename='so-parser.log'):
  logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(dump_path, log_filename), level=logging.INFO)
  db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(dump_path, dump_database_name))
  for file in file_names:
      print("Opening {0}.xml".format(file))
      with open(os.path.join(dump_path, file + '.xml')) as xml_file:
          tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
          table_name = file.lower()

          sql_create = create_query.format(
              table=table_name,
              fields=", ".join(['{0} {1}'.format(name, type) for name, type in anathomy[table_name].items()]))
          print('Creating table {0}'.format(table_name))

          try:
              logging.info(sql_create)
              db.execute(sql_create)
          except Exception as e:
              logging.warning(e)

          count = 0
          for events, row in tree:
              try:
                  if row.attrib.values():
                      logging.debug(row.attrib.keys())
                      query = insert_query.format(
                          table=table_name,
                          columns=', '.join(row.attrib.keys()),
                          values=('?, ' * len(row.attrib.keys()))[:-2])
                      vals = []
                      for key, val in row.attrib.items():
                          if anathomy[table_name][key] == 'INTEGER':
                              vals.append(int(val))
                          elif anathomy[table_name][key] == 'BOOLEAN':
                              vals.append(1 if val=="TRUE" else 0)
                          else:
                              vals.append(val)
                      db.execute(query, vals)

                      count += 1
                      if (count % 1000 == 0):
                          print("{}".format(count))

              except Exception as e:
                  logging.warning(e)
                  print("x", end="")
              finally:
                  row.clear()
          print("\n")
          db.commit()
          del (tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  dump_files(ANATHOMY.keys(), ANATHOMY)
```

Comment: I wouldn't usually post such a similar answer, but it took me an hour or so to make this work after starting from the other Python script; so, I thought I'd save people some time.

Comment: For the latest data dump (December 2017) line 125 should be `table_name = file.lower()`

Comment: @ayhan I've just updated the code without checking to see if that works; I'll trust you're right. :)

Comment: I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './badges.xml'` on Linux. For case-sensitive file systems you need to run something like `find . -iname '*.xml' -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;` to rename all xml files to lowercase before running the script.

Comment: After that, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2005-2006: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on macOS High Sierra using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

## MS SQL Server 2000/05/08 - MySQL 5.1 - SQLite3

C#

Tested and working on release(s):

- March 2010 - all sites, any way you want it. 5 to 17 minutes depending on options

---

Here is a Windows application that will import to MySQL, MS SQL Server and SQLite:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-2000-05-08-sqlite-mysql

Answer (score 2):

## .xml data dump files to R data frame

I think that this code could be (somewhat) useful if someone need data in R but for some reason want to read this .xml data directly. But remember that R is still R and (if dataset will be to big for resources you have) could crash due to lack of RAM.

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)

xmlDataDumpToDataFrame<- function(xmlFilePath){

  doc <- xmlParse(xmlFilePath)  
  xmlList<- xmlToList(doc)

  total<-length(xmlList)

  print(paste0("Parsing file : ", xmlFilePath ))
  progressBar <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)

  data<-data.frame()

  for(i in 1: total){
    data <- rbind.fill(data,as.data.frame(as.list( xmlList[[i]])))
    setTxtProgressBar(progressBar, i)
  }
  close(progressBar)

  print(paste0("created object size : ", format(object.size(data), units= "Mb") ))

  return(data)
}
```

Usage example:

```
usersData <- xmlDataDumpToDataFrame("stats.stackexchange.com/Users.xml")
```

As you can noticed, I also added a progress bar and an information how big created data frame is.

Answer (score 0):

## CSV converter

Implemented in **Pyspark**. This works in parallel, utilizing Apache Spark's RDDs and complete the conversion in **2-3 minutes for 1GB xml file with a minimal 2-core and 2 GB RAM Spark setup.**

Tested and working on release(s):

- March 2016 - all sites, any way you want it.
- Should be working on all previous versions also

Github repo containing the code - [XmltoCsv_StackExchange](https://github.com/adi11/XmltoCsv_StackExchange)

Comment: The Spark requirement is pesky if you don't have Spark and the ad-hoc function to slurp in a line at a time looks rather suspicious.  I created a simple proof of concept for exporting posts to CSV using Python cElementTree which avoids reading the entire tree into memory, and which  uses 52 seconds per gigabyte in my quick informal test (maybe the parallelism isn't really useful here?) I'ld appreciate any feedback: https://gist.github.com/tripleee/3ae578463d3c8b2f52f99b78cd31bbf7

Comment: @tripleee You did a good job. But there is a problem with the result of your script. CSV does not support new line inside cell value. But almost all the Posts body contain new line, so the CSV is broken. You should add a replace() after reading the cell to remove the \r and \n.

Comment: @J.M.Kenny Thanks for the feedback. I had forgotten about this. But as a matter of fact, CSV does support newlines inside fields, as long as those fields are quoted. The Python `csv` library should take care of this. Are you using something less savvy to read them?

Comment: Perhaps you have this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value (As if there weren't enough reasons to avoid Excel already!)

Comment: Ok. I used the generated import to upload the CSV into a database, but it looks like their CSV reader is broken then. I ended up removing the newlines since they are not necessary for my purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### R script using purrr and xml2

```
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

# function taking path and returning data frame
xml_to_frame<-function(path){
  data <- read_xml(path) %>%
    xml_find_all("//row") %>% 
    map(xml_attrs) %>% 
    map_df(~as.list(.))
  return(data)
}

# path to frame
votes<-xml_to_frame("votes.xml")

# frame to CSV
votes %>% fwrite("votes.csv")
```

This works a lot faster than most other R implementations as it [avoids looping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7142767/3367799) over the rows. This does read the entire XML into memory but it's still useful for most smaller sites. You can probably adapt `xml_find_all()` to read blocks of rows (e.g. read a 40GB file in three chunks) but I haven't found (or needed) that option yet.