# Using the data dump without MS SQL?

Tags: support, data-dump, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

I was wondering how I can use the data dump to query for answers offline (on a MacOS box)? - I recently saw some people using it with MS SQL setups... but that's more than cumbersome.

Did anybody write a specific app jet, that has got a lower footprint? It's just to issue some queries, because the answers are really time-saving and enhancing my productivity.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-2000-05-08-sqlite-mysql) for all your datadump conversion needs :)

Answer (score 0):

I had made some time ago a quick Python script to create and import the date into a SQLite3 database from the data dump, but I haven't test it with the last few months data dumps. You'l surely will have to modify the `ANATHOMY` dictionary to fit the current version.