# How to read data dump of a site

Tags: support, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

I downloaded data dump of one closed site at SE but it is all XML. Is there a proper way/tool to read it? Or I have to format it myself?

I know about XML editors but I want a more readable form such as on a page or in Question/Answer format.

Answer (score 1):

The data dump, as its name suggests is simply the server **dumping** its contents into a file.  There is no way to read *that* file easily.

You'll have to load it into your choice of database and query/display it from there.

---

I came across this post which might be of some assistance -

[Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started to is to load the contents of the data dump into a database (such as MSSQL Server or MySQL).

There is an article [here](http://mines.humanoriented.com/classes/2010/fall/csci568/portfolio_exports/jthomas/stackoverflow.html) about mining data from the data dumps using some PHP scripts and a MySQL database.

There is also a [utility found on GitHub called "So-Slow"](https://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow) which can import the data into a MSSQL Server database.

Be aware that the data dump is *fairly hefty*.  Importing this data is going to take a while :)