# How to import the Stack Overflow data dump

Tags: support, data-dump

I downloaded the Stack Overflow data dump for the last month. It has six files, with names like **stackoverflow.com.7z.001**, **stackoverflow.com.7z.002**, etc. I tried to open one of them with [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++), it showed a pile of binary data, suggesting that it might be a dump. Now, how do I import it into MySQL?

Is the dump already in format **Insert into table values ()**, or is it just the data in some space separated or [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format, that has to be loaded? Plus any idea about the table schemas? The Meta Stack Overflow post *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678)* gives you an idea about the nature of the data the tables contain, but it doesn't tell you about the schema.

Comment: Where did you download the data ? Can you pls provide me the link ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/do-you-want-to-quickly-and-easily-import-the-so-data-dump-into-your-sql-server/44365#44365. You will find the link 2 or 3 answers down.

Comment: You might find the following project helpful: https://github.com/1123/StackExchangeImporter. It is based upon JPA and you should be able to import the XML dumps to any relational database.

Comment: If you are importing to MySQL you might want to use the following SQL script: https://gist.github.com/gousiosg/7600626

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post you link to, [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678), *is* the schema; so yes it does contain the schema. You can get column sizes from the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) if you want.

You might find [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats) helpful.

The fact that the files are `.001`, `.002`, etc. would imply that it's been split. Probably using [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip)'s split functionality. You can either use 7-Zip to [recombine them](https://superuser.com/questions/36862/good-free-software-that-will-join-001-files) or use another tool such as [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/).

Comment: By schema I meant the table structure, structure of the columns. This post only describes what each column represents, for example, name of the voter, his id, etc, whereas I want to know whether that column is of type **char(50)** or **varchar(100)**.

Comment: @Cupidvogel Ben already answered this, you can get the column types & sizes from Data Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, the scripts are very helpful. I'm able to convert them to SQL Server scripts.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey can you share your SQL Server scripts?