# Download Stack Overflow data for a research project

Tags: support, data-dump

I would like to download the Stack Overflow data for a data mining research project. I tried the SQL interface at data.stackexchange.com, but the downloading process was not obvious since the result of any SQL query is limited to 50,000 rows only.

Is there any efficient way to download the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grab the latest [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) as well.

Note that these are basically in XML, so you will likely need to import it to your database of choice. Here are a couple links to help with that:

- [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/do-you-want-to-quickly-and-easily-import-the-so-data-dump-into-your-sql-server

Comment: The data dump link seems to have expired. Any updated link, please? UPDATE: Ok, found this link [dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Comment: @CoderaPurpa Oh, right. Sorry 'bout that. Link updated.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/), the Machine Learning Contest has a large dataset available for download.