# My project requires data from Stack Overflow. What can I do?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, api, faq-proposed

I want to make research on Stack Overflow (or any other Stack Exchange website).

How can I parse the website's data <s>using regular expressions</s>?

Comment: I'd like to point out this arrived in my inbox because of a filter subscription and the strikeout isn't preserved there, so I was very scared to click through until I saw who the author was.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1068283)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put Beautiful Soup down and forget about [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13992). There's way better tools at your disposal than screen scraping.

#### Before you start

Please keep the following in mind as you consume the data, regardless of how you obtain it:

- The [terms of use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/)
- The [data license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
- The [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)
- The [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Once you are comfortable with the legalese, choose wisely from these three options according to your needs:

---

## [Offline ~quarterly XML data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)

If you want data from a Stack Exchange site for offline use, SE makes monthly "database dumps" available in 7zipped XML format. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28221/13992) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/do-you-want-to-quickly-and-easily-import-the-so-data-dump-into-your-sql-server) explain how to wrangle the XML data back into a useful format. Those dumps are only built occasionally.

You can get help on the Stack Exchange data dump on this site through the [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump) tag.

#### [→ Read the data scheme documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

#### [→ Get the data dump torrent file](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent)

---

## [Weekly data you can run SQL queries on](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

If you can make do with SQL queries that return 50,000 lines at most, you can save yourself a 6 GB download and get somewhat fresher data on [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com). You can download the query results in CSV format. Make sure you log in so you don't have to fill in (as many) captchas.

You can get help on the Data Stack Exchange on this site through the [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag.

#### [→ Read the data scheme documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

#### [→ Query the Stack Overflow database](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

---

## [Fresh JSON data through a throttled API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

While this data is updated every minute, you have to respect [a number of throttling and caching considerations](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) while using the API or have your requests dropped with maximum prejudice. That said, the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) is extensive and you can easily [try queries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events). You can even [vectorize your queries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) and [create custom filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) so you can fetch just the information you need.

You can get help on the Stack Exchange API through [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/support)

#### [→ Read the API documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

#### [→ Register for a Stack Exchange app](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)

---

## [Academic access through the Digital Ecologies Research Partnership](http://derp.institute/)

> DERP is an alliance of platforms supporting the academic exploration of communities online for the betterment of the internet at large. [...]
>
> DERP focuses on providing public data to academic researchers while facilitating an active online research community of Fellows. DERP will only support research that respects user privacy, responsibly uses data, and meets IRB approval. All research supported by DERP will be released openly and made publicly available. Partner platforms may also have additional guidelines and privacy commitments that apply to the research they support.

If this sounds like you, visit their website. For bonus points, you'll also find information about Reddit, Twitch, imgur and Fark.

#### [→ Visit website](http://derp.institute/)

#### → inquire@derp.institute

Comment: Should I mention search results based RSS feeds as a kind-of low-tech solution?

Comment: In some cases, scraping is the only option. For example, I wanted to make a list of [all SE 2.0 sites launched](https://github.com/asheeshr/stack-exchange/blob/master/data/sitelist.csv) and the only reliable method is through A51. A51 is not supported  by the API or SEDE and the data dumps are not exactly fresh.

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites @AsheeshR

Comment: @Mat By *launched*, I mean sites that have graduated, are in beta, or [went into beta and were closed.](https://github.com/asheeshr/stack-exchange/blob/master/data/sitelist.csv#L4)