# SE Q-A available as downloads

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if Physics.SE or other SE sites have this feature.

If they don't, I suggest a new feature. Can we have the questions and answers available as downloads. We can simply save the html file but it's tiresome when one wants to download too many questions. Can we have a topic-wise(or should I say tag-wise) collection of different questions? It maybe be a great help to students and teachers as it can show the wide range of questions which can arise out of a topic and it can also address some common misconceptions.

We can have it like a separate set of files for questions related to a particular phenomenon. For, example all questions related to Hawking Radiation available as download.

EDIT: For example, [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) page is an archive of deleted popular questions.

Comment: "this page is an archive of deleted popular questions." - what page?..

Comment: You can get a data dump of all Stack Exchange sites at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @nicael Edited the question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/my-project-requires-data-from-stack-overflow-what-can-i-do

Comment: @Oded Thanks. I wanted something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will suit you.

There is a thing called [Stack printer](http://www.stackprinter.com).

- Click on this link
- write id of a question - the id of this question is 232402:

  > meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ **232402** /se-q-a-available-as-downloads
- chose site (Physics, for example)
- print
- copy text
- open Notepad (or TextEdit, if you are on Mac)
- past text
- save.

Comment: I know about stack printer. We have an easier way. Just right click on the page and save it. But what I am asking for is organised questions and answers(like a set of them) available as downloads.