# How can SO query's result did not encrypt the id?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, ssl

What's the reason [StackExchange Data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) website didnt encrypt the id of the query result ? I mean it's just give the result like `postId=1` or `postId=655011`. Does it make the data in SO vulnerable from cybercrime/hacker attack ? why they didn't change that so it would give us the result like `postId=asldkjLKJlkajamsnd718LKJlkjasd` ?

Comment: What is valuable about the posts that it need obscurity to protect its functional key?

Comment: consider that you can simply download all the data off the internet, and those are santitised, static snapshots of the SE databases... not sure what real threat you're worried about.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well it feels like "this is not okay... this is totally wrong"... and that's it..

Comment: Why didn't you encrypt your question? I am serious. Now anyone can read what you wrote, and track it back to you, and hack your computer. You really should encrypt any bit you send over the internet, if your paranoia level is so high.

Comment: @ShadowWizard cRY/bRGNujjHnvd1ClKR1lalTTKxLs/iCb0Umcu9kUHki9DlZ7+DoSt4eNjKdpw=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encryption? We don't need no encryption (for postids). Its all public data. If you weren't meant to see it, say with a deleted post for a sub 10ker , you typically don't since your access level is based off your 'role' and your post ID on the main page is *right there in the URL*

[image]

This is off the *live, production* MSE instance. (and answers use the same series of postids! This was postid 305995)

SEDE is sanitised, *static* and based off data [you can download](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/my-project-requires-data-from-stack-overflow-what-can-i-do/232086#232086) *right now*, tho SEDE is based off more regular data dumps. Having reasonably predictable ways to call things probably makes scripting and coding around SEDE or the datadumps simple, and many of these things would likely work elsewhere.

There's no sense in encrypting things meant for public consumption.

I'd also add, If you can find a real *practical* exploit involving SE's systems *report it* directly and [you will be in the SO security hall of fame](https://stackexchange.com/about/security). The nice thing about a community with a broad audience of developers and other folk is there's people who notice the obvious, and try to break the less obvious for fun.

Comment: what about user id ?

Comment: Can't really do much with that. Did you know your userID's on your share links? Its quite literally a semi meaningless number generated in series as you sign up to a site. You don't even get respect for a low user number ala slashdot. You can't pull up anything particularly tasty on SEDE that you wouldn't notice with a username on the main site. Your userid is on your *profile*... so... ehh. Non issue.