# Is it possible to get more detailed voting information?

Tags: support, research

I'm doing some research on Stack Exchange data. It would be helpful for our research to get more detailed information on voting. I understand this is not generally available in the information Stack Exchange releases to the public.

Is there any avenue for working with Stack Exchange to get access to more detailed data for research purposes?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/my-project-requires-data-from-stack-overflow-what-can-i-do