# Can we get the Stack Exchange Data Dump as an SQL file?

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Currently, the [data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) that are released periodically are MDF files. Would it possible to release them in the SQL format as well, to make it easier for MySQL users to use the data?

Comment: See this: [Scripts to convert data-dump to other formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats)

Comment: @HackerKarma - Cool, thanks for the link. I looked at several SO questions about converting it, but a lot of the answers involved using old tools and didn't give clear instructions.